Unable to List Facebook Pages via Graph API for Business Manager Admin User
I'm encountering an issue with the Facebook Graph API where one of my users, User Chris, cannot list his Facebook pages despite being an administrator in Business Manager. Here's the breakdown:
Users:
User Hana
Access Token Permissions:

email
pages_show_list
ads_management
business_management
leads_retrieval
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_manage_ads
public_profile

Behavior: Successfully lists pages using GET https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/accounts
User Chris
Access Token Permissions:

email
pages_show_list
ads_management
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_manage_ads
public_profile
Missing Permissions:
business_management
leads_retrieval

Behavior: Fails to list pages using GET https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/accounts
Additional Context:
User Chris is an administrator in Business Manager, and his pages are managed through it.
When User Hana was directly added as an administrator to a page outside of Business Manager, that page started appearing in her API results.
Both users obtain their access tokens via the standard OAuth flow, and the application has been approved for the necessary permissions except for User Chris's token, which lacks business_management and leads_retrieval.
Steps Taken So Far:

Verified User Chris's role in Business Manager.
Ensured the application requests all necessary permissions during authentication.
Used the /debug_token endpoint to confirm User Chris's token permissions.
Attempted to re-authenticate User Chris to obtain a new token, but the missing permissions persist.

Question:
Is there a specific configuration or additional step required to ensure that administrators in Business Manager, like User Chris, have their access tokens include the business_management and leads_retrieval permissions?
